# print a list of dictionaries in table form

Tags: python

assume I have this list as global list

```
 dataset =[{'Major': 'Biology', 'GPA': '2.4', 'Name': 'Edward'},
           {'Major': 'Physics', 'GPA': '2.9', 'Name':'Emily'},  
           {'Major':'Mathematics', 'GPA': '3.5', 'Name': 'Sarah'}]
```

and a want a function print() to print it as

```
 name     major        GPA 
 =============================== 
 edward   Biology      2.4 
 Emily    physics      2.9 
 sarah    mathematics  3.5
```

Comment: You write a function that iterates over the list and prints it out in whatever way you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

dataset =[{'Major': 'Biology', 'GPA': '2.4', 'Name': 'Edward'},Physics', 'GPA': '2.9', 'Name': 'Emily'},Mathematics', 'GPA': '3.5', 'Name': 'Sarah'}]

[print("%s %s: %s\n"%(item['Name'],item['Major'],item['GPA'])) for item in dataset]
```

result:

```
Edward Biology: 2.4

Emily Physics: 2.9

Sarah Mathematics: 3.5
```

Comment: Why make `printer` first?

Comment: No reason , removed it :D

Comment: This doesn't exactly match the expected format of the question

Comment: @cricket_007 When I wrote the answer the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40056747/1) was different from now. it was like this and my answer is a little "neater" than what the OP expected by using \n . I didn't know I have to come up and update my answer based on the 5-time-edited question.

Comment: You don't, but the [source of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1de76b81-ee4e-44ba-b815-4bacf1240461/view-source) looks fine.

Answer (score 42):

you can use module [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate).

```
>>> import tabulate
>>> dataset =[{'Major': 'Biology', 'GPA': '2.4', 'Name': 'Edward'}, {'Major': 'Physics', 'GPA': '2.9', 'Name': 'Emily'}, {'Major': 'Mathematics', 'GPA': '3.5', 'Name': 'Sarah'}]
>>> header = dataset[0].keys()
>>> rows =  [x.values() for x in dataset]
>>> print(tabulate.tabulate(rows, header))
Major          GPA  Name
-----------  -----  ------
Biology        2.4  Edward
Physics        2.9  Emily
Mathematics    3.5  Sarah
```

you can use `tablefmt` parameter for different table format

```
>>> print(tabulate.tabulate(rows, header, tablefmt='grid'))
+-------------+-------+--------+
| Major       |   GPA | Name   |
+=============+=======+========+
| Biology     |   2.4 | Edward |
+-------------+-------+--------+
| Physics     |   2.9 | Emily  |
+-------------+-------+--------+
| Mathematics |   3.5 | Sarah  |
+-------------+-------+--------+
>>> print tabulate.tabulate(rows, header, tablefmt='rst')
===========  =====  ======
Major          GPA  Name
===========  =====  ======
Biology        2.4  Edward
Physics        2.9  Emily
Mathematics    3.5  Sarah
===========  =====  ======
```

Comment: What a handy library

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yea it is very handy indeed, thanks :)

Comment: ImportError: No module named 'tabulate'

Comment: Install the `tabulate` module.  `pip install tabulate` should work I guess.

Comment: @Huda in terminal type `pip install tabulate`

Comment: it says  install  is invalid syntax

Comment: This will run into `headers for a list of dicts is not a dict or a keyword` with python 3, see [e.g. here](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate/issues/39/valueerror-headers-for-a-list-of-dicts-is) for python 3.

Comment: tabulate is great! It can be used directly for a list of dicts. In this case the header should be 'keys'.

Comment: just `print(tabulate.tabulate(dataset, headers='keys'))` is ok

Answer (score 6):

```
for dicts in dataset:
    print(dicts.get('Name')),
    print(dicts.get('Major')),
    print(dicts.get('GPA')),
```

Example

```
>>> dataset =[{'Major': 'Biology', 'GPA': '2.4', 'Name': 'Edward'}, {'Major': 'Physics', 'GPA': '2.9', 'Name': 'Emily'}, {'Major': 'Mathematics', 'GPA': '3.5', 'Name': 'Sarah'}]
>>> 
>>> for dicts in dataset:
...         print(dicts.get('Name')),
...         print(dicts.get('Major')),
...         print(dicts.get('GPA')),
... 
Edward Biology 2.4 Emily Physics 2.9 Sarah Mathematics 3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

For a structured output in matrix format, I would go with something like this:

```
dataset =[{'Name': 'Edward', 'Major': 'Biology',     'GPA': '2.4'},
          {'Name': 'Emily',  'Major': 'Physics',     'GPA': '2.9'},
          {'Name': 'Sarah',  'Major': 'Mathematics', 'GPA': '3.5'}]
​
keys = []
vals = []
for data in dataset:
    val = []
    for k,v in data.items():
        keys.append(k)
        val.append(v)
    vals.append(val)
​
print(list(dict.fromkeys(keys)))
for v in vals:
    print(v)

['Name', 'Major', 'GPA']
['Edward', 'Biology', '2.4']
['Emily', 'Physics', '2.9']
['Sarah', 'Mathematics', '3.5']
```

This way, you can also use pandas if you like:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset =[{'Name': 'Edward', 'Major': 'Biology',     'GPA': '2.4'},
          {'Name': 'Emily',  'Major': 'Physics',     'GPA': '2.9'},
          {'Name': 'Sarah',  'Major': 'Mathematics', 'GPA': '3.5'}]

keys = []
vals = []
for data in dataset:
    val = []
    for k,v in data.items():
        keys.append(k)
        val.append(v)
    vals.append(val)

pd.DataFrame([v for v in vals], columns=list(dict.fromkeys(keys)))

    Name    Major       GPA
0   Edward  Biology     2.4
1   Emily   Physics     2.9
2   Sarah   Mathematics 3.5
```

Of course, there are much simpler methods with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset =[{'Name': 'Edward', 'Major': 'Biology',     'GPA': '2.4'},
          {'Name': 'Emily',  'Major': 'Physics',     'GPA': '2.9'},
          {'Name': 'Sarah',  'Major': 'Mathematics', 'GPA': '3.5'}]

pd.DataFrame(dataset).reindex(columns=['Name','Major','GPA'])

    Name    Major       GPA
0   Edward  Biology     2.4
1   Emily   Physics     2.9
2   Sarah   Mathematics 3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Dissatisifed with the benachmarks of [tabulate &co](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate#performance-considerations) i wrote a doc'd, performant asciifier function for dicts. timeit: <1ms vs tabulate's 21ms in plain format.

It is versatile with custom converters, formatting, column exclusion and value replacements. Yet fast since its addon like: minimal MWE is
`print(tabulate_dict([{'col1':'v1'}, {'col1':'v2'}]))`

```
col1
----
v1
v2
```

```
def tabulate_dict(dicts: List[Dict], keys: List[str] = None, pads: List[str] = None, fcodes: List[str] = None,
                  convert_headers: Dict[str, Callable] = None, header_names: List[str] = None,
                  skip_none_lines: bool = False, replace_values: Dict[str, Any] = None):
    """ Generate ascii table from dictionary
    dicts: input dictionary list; empty lists make keys OR header_names mandatory
    keys: order list of keys to generate columns for; no key/dict-key should suffix with '____' else adjust code-suffix
    pads: indicate padding direction and size, eg <10 to right pad alias left-align
    fcodes: formating codes for respective column type, eg .3f
    convert_headers: apply converters(dict) on column keys k, eg timestamps
    header_names: supply for custom column headers instead of keys
    skip_none_lines: skip line if contains None
    replace_values: specify per column keys k a map from seen value to new value;
                    new value must comply with the columns fcode; CAUTION: modifies input (due speed)
    """
    # optional arg prelude
    if keys is None:
        if len(dicts) > 0:
            keys = dicts[0].keys()
        elif header_names is not None:
            keys = header_names
        else:
            raise ValueError('keys or header_names mandatory on empty input list')
    if pads is None:
        pads = [''] * len(keys)
    elif len(pads) != len(keys):
        raise ValueError(f'bad pad length {len(pads)}, expected: {len(keys)}')
    if fcodes is None:
        fcodes = [''] * len(keys)
    elif len(fcodes) != len(fcodes):
        raise ValueError(f'bad fcodes length {len(fcodes)}, expected: {len(keys)}')
    if convert_headers is None:
        convert_headers = {}
    if header_names is None:
        header_names = keys
    if replace_values is None:
        replace_values = {}
    # build header
    headline = '│'.join(f"{v:{pad}}" for v, pad in zip_longest(header_names, pads))
    underline = '─' * len(headline)
    # suffix special keys to apply converters to later on
    marked_keys = [h + '____' if h in convert_headers else h for h in keys]
    marked_values = {}
    s = '│'.join(f"{{{h}:{pad}{fcode}}}" for h, pad, fcode in zip_longest(marked_keys, pads, fcodes))
    lines = [headline, underline, ]
    for d in dicts:
        none_keys = [k for k, v in d.items() if v is None]
        if skip_none_lines and none_keys:
            continue
        elif replace_values:
            for k in d.keys():
                if k in replace_values and d[k] in replace_values[k]:
                    d[k] = replace_values[k][d[k]]
                if d[k] is None:
                    raise ValueError(f"bad or no mapping for key '{k}' is None. Use skip or change replace mapping.")
        elif none_keys:
            raise ValueError(f'keys {none_keys} are None in {d}. Do skip or use replace mapping.')
        for h in convert_headers:
            if h in keys:
                converter = convert_headers[h]
                marked_values[h + '____'] = converter(d)
        line = s.format(**d, **marked_values)
        lines.append(line)
    return '\n'.join(lines)
```

computed columns? np:
`print(tabulate_dict([{'col1':1}, {'col1':2}], keys=['col1', 'comp1'], pads=['<5', '>4'],convert_headers={'comp1': lambda d: d['col1']+1}))`

The output is

```
col1 │comp1
───────────
1    │   2
2    │   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on previous answers (with tabulate)

### Define helper

```py
from tabulate import tabulate
import shutil

def table_print(dataSet: list) -> None:
  headers = dataSet[0].keys()
  rows = [x.values() for x in dataSet]
  maxColWidths = get_max_col_width(headers)
  tabulated = tabulate(
    rows,
    headers=headers,
    tablefmt="simple_grid",
    maxcolwidths=maxColWidths
  )
  print(tabulated)

def get_max_col_width(headers) -> list:
  numCols = len(headers)
  shellColumns = shutil.get_terminal_size((80, 20)).columns
  maxColSingle = shellColumns / numCols
  return [maxColSingle] * numCols
```

### Usage

```py
dataset = [
  {
    "Major": "Biology",
    "GPA": "2.4",
    "Name": "Edward"
  },
  {
    "Major": "Physics",
    "GPA": "2.9",
    "Name": "Emily"
  },
  {
    "Major": "Mathematics",
    "GPA": "3.5",
    "Name": "Sarah"
  }
]

table_print(dataset)
```

```py
┌─────────────┬───────┬────────┐
│ Major       │   GPA │ Name   │
├─────────────┼───────┼────────┤
│ Biology     │   2.4 │ Edward │
├─────────────┼───────┼────────┤
│ Physics     │   2.9 │ Emily  │
├─────────────┼───────┼────────┤
│ Mathematics │   3.5 │ Sarah  │
└─────────────┴───────┴────────┘
```